Can't install Hotspot M1 Mac OS 13.7 QGIS 3.34.11
Trying to install Hotspot Analysis plugin on
M1 Mac Ventura 13.7
QGIS 3.34.11-Prizren QGIS code revision 2904bcec7c9
Getting this error on install.  Tried both prepending and appending newer numpy to PYTHONPATH as noted in the trace below.  Not sure where to go next.
Couldn't load plugin 'HotspotAnalysis' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 

ImportError: C extension: None not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext' to build the C extensions first. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 26, in 
    from pandas.compat import (
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 892, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 26, in 
    from pandas.compat.numpy import is_numpy_dev
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 892, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/compat/numpy/__init__.py", line 21, in 
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: this version of pandas is incompatible with numpy your numpy version is 1.20.1.
Please upgrade numpy to >= 1.22.4 to use this pandas version

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 423, in _startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "/Users/.../Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/HotspotAnalysis/__init__.py", line 34, in classFactory
    from .hotspot_analysis import HotspotAnalysis
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 892, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Users/.../Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/HotspotAnalysis/hotspot_analysis.py", line 38, in 
    import pysal
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 892, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pysal/__init__.py", line 3, in 
    from . import explore
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 892, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pysal/explore/__init__.py", line 4, in 
    from . import pointpats
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 892, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pysal/explore/pointpats/__init__.py", line 4, in 
    from .pointpattern import PointPattern
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 892, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pysal/explore/pointpats/pointpattern.py", line 11, in 
    import pandas as pd
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 892, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 31, in 
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: C extension: None not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext' to build the C extensions first.


Python version: 3.9.5 (default, Sep 10 2021, 16:18:19) [Clang 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)] 
QGIS version: 3.34.11-Prizren Prizren, 2904bcec7c9 

Python Path:
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python
/Users/angelinavaron/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/Users/angelinavaron/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/patsy-0.5.1-py3.9.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba-0.50.1-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib-3.3.0-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Fiona-1.8.13.post1-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels-0.11.1-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rasterio-1.1.5-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Pillow-7.2.0-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/opencv_contrib_python-4.3.0.36-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyproj-3.2.0-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas-1.3.3-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas-0.8.1-py3.9.egg
/Users/.../Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy-1.20.1-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cftime-1.2.1-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/GDAL-3.3.2-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Rtree-0.9.7-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python39.zip
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/netCDF4-1.5.4-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Users/.../Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/Users/.../Desktop/Powassan manuscript/NYS case maps

